# MISRA rule 18.3 preventing copying data to RAM

Tags: c, embedded, misra

MISRA has a problem with the following code:

```
extern uint32_t __etext;
extern uint32_t __data_start__, __data_end__;
uint32_t* src = (uint32_t*)&__etext;        // ROM location of code to be copied into ram
uint32_t* dst = (uint32_t*)&__data_start__; // Start of RAM data section

while (dst  < &__data_end__) // Loop until we reach the end of the data section
{
    *dst++ = *src++;
}
```

I am getting a violation for rule 18.3:

The relational operators >, >=, < and <= shall not be applied to objects of pointer type except when they point to the same object.”

The rationale behind the rule is that attempting to make comparisons between pointers will produce undefined behavior if the two pointers do not point to the same object.

Why is this incorrect code? This seems like pretty generic boot code which is doing the right thing.

Comment: ugh you know what, I think this is my static anzlyer getting confused about what data_end and data_start are because the linker actually provides them

Comment: Not only your static code analyzer, also your compiler thinks you are comparing two pointers pointing to different objects. Since the pointers are `extern`, they cannot know that actually the pointers point to the same "object", the raw memory. -- I'm curious how this could be resolved. ("Best" bet for now: silence your analyzer.)

Comment: Oh, and you might like to change the question at the bottom, since you know why this is "incorrect" code.

Comment: You must tag MISRA questions with either C or C++. We shouldn't need to guess which one you are using. Also, in case of MISRA C you should mention which version you are using.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, you have missing `volatile` bugs all over the place. This might cause incorrect code generation.

Comment: I'm not sure you are correct here. These are externally defined addresses.

Answer (score 3):

MISRA C:2012 *required* Rule 18.3 is *undecidable* because it is often impossible to determine, statically, whether two pointers are pointing to the same object.

In the example cited, as long as you can demonstrate that the two pointers are, indeed, pointing to the same object (or block of memory) and that `__data_end__` is higher up the memory map than `__data_start__` then this is an easy documentation task.

s3.4 of [MISRA Compliance](https://www.misra.org.uk/app/uploads/2021/06/MISRA-Compliance-2020.pdf) applies - this appears to fall within Category (2).  This is not the same as a formal deviation, but does still need appropiate review/signoff.

Whatever you do, **do not** change the code to try and create some clever mechanism that you claim is MISRA compliant!

Comment: The code as it stands invokes UB so unless the compiler can guarantee deterministic behavior beyond standard C, the code _has_ to be changed. Also there are numerous other problems unrelated to this rule (and some unrelated to MISRA), so it has to be rewritten pretty much from scratch anyway.

Comment: Fair point.....

Comment: Is it? I struggle to see how the code invokes UB if both addresses are indeed pointing at the same array object.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this incorrect code? This seems like pretty generic boot code which is doing the right thing.

Because the code invokes undefined behavior, as specified by the C standard (additive operators 6.5.6/8), MISRA or no MISRA. For this reason, the compiler might generate incorrect code.

Possible work-arounds:

- Create a big array or struct object covering the whole area to copy from and the area to copy into.
- Use a compiler with a known and documented non-standard extension which allows you address absolute addresses regardless of what happens to be stored there. Then document it yourself in turn, in your MISRA documentation. (Most embedded compilers should support this. gcc might, but I don't know how without looking it up.)
- Use integers instead of pointers and deviate from the MISRA rule regarding casting between integers and pointers. Which is an impossible rule to follow in embedded systems anyway.

Other problems:

- (Severe) You have missing `volatile` bugs all over the code, which could result in incorrect code generation.
- (Severe) You aren't using `const` correctness for variables stored in ROM which is surely a bug.
- (Severe) Using `extern` in a safety/mission-critical application is highly questionable practice.
- (Minor) Identifiers starting with double underscore are reserved by the compiler. If this code is from your home-made CRT it might be ok, but not if this code is from some generic bootloader.
- (Minor) `*dst++ = *src++;` violates MISRA C 13.3. You need to do `*dst = *src; dst++; src++;`.

Answer (score 0):

With linker defined symbols like this, the only way to satisfy this rule (without breaking 18.2 instead) is to cast the pointers to integers before comparing them.  I don't think this change would help readability, so I would suggest making an exemption (called a "deviation record" in MISRA) and disabling the rule for this line of code.

Comment: Well... converting a pointer to an integer violates R.11.4

Comment: @Andrew 11.4 is impossible to follow in embedded systems anyhow. And it's better to violate Advisory rules than Required.

Comment: While converting an integer (an address) to a pointer is common, I'm not sure how common the real need for the reverse is?

Comment: @Andrew This is one of the examples, when pointer arithmetic for various reasons is problematic. Another scenario is an interrupt vector table, present in pretty much every embedded system, which can be implemented as an array of integers rather than an array of function pointers. Another case is when implementing a flash/eeprom driver using pointers as API but you need to perform various calculations on the addresses, such as range and alignment checks.

Comment: Like: `void write_to_eeprom (volatile const* dst_in_eeprom, const* src_in_ram)`. Before commencing the eeprom burn, you'll want to check if `dst_in_eeprom` is actually a destination in eeprom. So you need to check against upper and lower limits, most often stored in the form of integer `#define` constants. Can't be done with a pointer since it's UB. The OP's code in this question is somewhat similar.

Comment: We accept that sometimes Rules need to be deviated - and we even have Permits for some of those use cases (eg access to hardware)... but such use should easily be separated out from the user-level stuff to make such checks constrained.